# GridView item selector checked state not appearing

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-selector

I have a `GridView` with a bunch of items that are being populated using a custom adapter.  The grid view is set to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` in java, and I'm able to select things using the contextual action bar (all of this works fine).

I want the grid items to highlight when pressed and have a different highlight when selected (exactly the behavior you'll see in the Gallery app in ICS).

I have a selector which is being specified in the grid view XML like so: `listSelector="@drawable/grid_item_selector"`.  I have also specified `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"`.  Here is the selector XML:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/grid_item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```

The pressed state works perfectly.  However, the checked/selected states never appear.

Even if I set an item to be checked in my java code, the checked state never appears.

I can't set the selector as the background of the grid items themselves because I need the selected state drawable to be the foreground, not the background.

Answer (score 1):

The selector only shows on the thing that you're touching. Once you take your finger off it no longer displays.

So, what I've ended up doing is having a View at the bottom of the layout (so it appears on top) with a background set to a selector.
The selector only has anything for state_selected.
The OS handles the rest.

Not exactly the nicest, but it works...